# cordova. time input skip 5 minutes at a time

Tags: cordova

I need the time-input to skip 5 minutes at a time, like this:

```
<input type="time" step="300">
```

But cordova doesnt heed the step="300" instruction. Is there a way to achieve skipping minutes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An input field of type 'time' is an HTML5 construct, so its rendering and behavior will be up to your device's underlying web engine, and possibly the Javascript framework that you're using to build your app.

Although the [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html) doesn't appear mention it, the `step` attribute works in conjunction with the `min` and `max` attributes; at least `min` should be set. Take a look at the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) for more info, or better yet, review the documentation for your target devices' web engines.